# Can't send a submit fetch request

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I searched for a long time without results about this question. The problem is that when I try to send an asynchronous request to another web page I don't have any response. I think the problem is where the FormData takes its values but I don't know why... Here is the code:

```js
const addBooking_form = document.getElementById("form_addResa");

addBooking_form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Send asynchronous request to /api/booking/new
    const formData = new FormData(addBooking_form);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(formData);

    console.log(formData);
    console.log(searchParams);
    const asyncReqAdd = fetch("api/booking/new", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    });
    asyncReqAdd.then(response => {
        return console.log(response.text() == 'undefined' ? 'Fetch reponse <=> undefined' : response);
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        table.innerHTML = response;
    });
    return console.log('New booking submited');
})
```

I know that the link and the form id are correct...

HTML FORM :

```
<form id="form_addResa">
        <div class="fieldset flexCol-around">
            <label for="input_lieu">Lieu *</label>
            <select id="input_lieu" name="place">
                <option value="none">&lt; Séléctionner un lieu &gt;</option>
                <option value="Salammbô">Salammbô</option>
                <option value="Pergola">Pergola</option>
                <option value="Salon Jaune">Salon Jaune</option>
                <option value="1001 Bougies">1001 bougies</option>
            </select>
            <div class="flexRow-around">
                <div class="flexCol-around">
                    <label for="input_date">Date *</label>
                    <input id="input_date" type="date" name="date">
                </div>
                <div class="flexCol-around">
                    <label for="input_time">Heure *</label>
                    <input id="input_time" type="time" name="time">
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="input_nom">Nom *</label>
            <input id="input_nom" type="text" name="name">
            <label for="input_prenom">Prénom *</label>
            <input id="input_prenom" type="text" name="firstName">
        </div>
        <div class="fieldset flexCol-around">
            <label for="input_couverts">Nombre de couverts *</label>
            <input id="input_couverts" type="number" name="coverts">
            <label for="input_intExt">Client interne / externe *</label>
            <select name="intExt" id="input_intExt">
                <option value="ext">Externe</option>
                <option value="int">Interne</option>
            </select>
            <label for="input_contacte">Contacter le client *</label>
            <input id="input_contacte" type="text" placeholder="Numéro de chambre / téléphone / E-mail" name="contact">
        </div>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <textarea id="input_note" placeholder="Note :" name="notes"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="flexRow-around">
            <input type="reset" value="Annuler" style="background: white;">
            <input type="submit" onclick="unselectBooking();">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Can you give me a solution for this?

Comment: So do you see anything in the console? Is there any clues in the browser Network tool about what happened to the request? It's unclear what you have checked already.

Comment: `return console.log` will return undefined

Comment: Can you also show the form element you're referencing? [`FormData` will only use input fields that use the name attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#retrieving_a_formdata_object_from_an_html_form)

Comment: I just noticed, shouldn't the URL passed to fetch be absolute? i.e. `https://yourdomain/api/booking/new` instead of `api/booking/new`

Comment: I already used the fetch method using te relative path and it works, but I passed parameters by this link and used a function....

Answer (score 1):

You could use async/await with a try catch block to see what goes wrong.

Something like this (pseudo):

```js
addBooking_form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { date, time, name, place } = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target))

    try {
      const respone = await fetch("api/booking/new", {
        method: "POST",
        body: { date, time, name, place }
      });
      const data = await response.json()
      // do something with data
      console.log(data)
    } catch(e) {
      // do some error handling
      console.log('error', e)
    }
})
```

Update: you can use `Object.formEntries` on `FormData` to get the values of your named input fields and then pass them to the body. This way, you should have valid JSON data.

I also removed the element selector since you already got the element via `event`

Comment: Ok, I tried your code and here is the console's answer :
error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Ah thats because FormData does not return JSON, I made a update to my answer

Comment: should I dclare each input name in the const {} = Object... ?

After I tried your code, I saw this error : ```error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (send_booking.js:24:35)```

And if I replace ```.json()``` by ```.text()``` I have : Nothing, a void console...